# How to make the landscape view look same as the portraitView while using a splitViewController?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

What I meant is, When we use a UISplitViewController project

In portrait mode, whole window will be covered by the view and a popoverController will be presented to navigate to other views. In landscape mode, 40% of the window will be covered by a tableView using which we can change the view/page. And navigation button as well as popoverController will be hidden.

What I want is,

Even in landscape mode, it should be like portrait mode. No tablewView should be there. Whole window should be covered with the view in landscape mode. For navigating to other pages, a navigation button as well as the popoverController should be there.

How can I do this?? Plz help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to your developer account, goto dev forums and search for "UISplitViewController settings.app". there's lots of talk about that there. The summary is you can't do it though that controller apparently has some private features which make it possible (file a bug report telling apple they should expose that capability).  There is a long discussion about building a splitview controller from scratch that mostly works this way.  Alternately, rethink your design.

Comment: yup, I have already redesigned my app. As u said, its not possible.

Comment: After looking through all the code one particular thread was putting together to recreate from scratch, and still having issues, I decided I'd wait until apple makes it possible. Shame though because the app I want this for just doesn't work with a hidden (left) tableview.